# Calculating limits in dynamic programming

Tags: c++11, math, dynamic

I found this question on topcoder:

> Your friend Lucas gave you a sequence S of positive integers.
>
> For a while, you two played a simple game with S: Lucas would pick a number, and you had to select some elements of S such that the sum of all numbers you selected is the number chosen by Lucas. For example, if S={2,1,2,7} and Lucas chose the number 11, you would answer that 2+2+7 = 11.
>
> Lucas now wants to trick you by choosing a number X such that there will be no valid answer. For example, if S={2,1,2,7}, it is not possible to select elements of S that sum up to 6.
>
> You are given the int[] S. Find the smallest positive integer X that cannot be obtained as the sum of some (possibly all) elements of S.
>
> Constraints: - S will contain between 1 and 20 elements, inclusive. - Each element of S will be between 1 and 100,000, inclusive.

But in the editorial solution it has been written:

> How about finding the smallest impossible sum? Well, we can try the following naive algorithm: First try with x = 1, if this is not a valid sum (found using the methods in the previous section), then we can return x, else we increment x and try again, and again until we find the smallest number that is not a valid sum.
>
> Let's find an upper bound for the number of iterations, the number of values of x we will need to try before we find a result. First of all, the maximum sum possible in this problem is 100000 * 20 (All numbers are the maximum 100000), this means that 100000 * 20 + 1 will not be an impossible value. We can be certain to need at most 2000001 steps.
>
> How good is this upper bound? If we had 100000 in each of the 20 numbers, 1 wouldn't be a possible sum. So we actually need one iteration in that case. If we want 1 to be a possible sum, we should have 1 in the initial elements. Then we need a 2 (Else we would only need 2 iterations), then a 4 (3 can be found by adding  1+2), then 8 (Numbers from 5 to 7 can be found by adding some of the first 3 powers of two), then 16, 32, .... It turns out that with the powers of 2, we can easily make inputs that require many iterations. With the first 17 powers of two, we can cover up to the first 262143 integer numbers. That should be a good estimation for the largest number. (We cannot use 2^18 in the input, smaller than 100000).
>
> Up to 262143 times, we need to query if a number x is in the set of possible sums. We can just use a boolean array here. It appears that even O(log(n)) data structures should be fast enough, however.

I did understand the first paragraph. But after that they have explained something about "How good is this upper bound?...". I couldnt understand that paragraph. How did they deduce to the fact that we need to query 262143 times if a number x is in the set of possible sums?

I am a newbie at dynamic programming and so it would be great if somebody could explain this to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is as follows:

If the input sequence contains the first `k` powers of two: `2^0, 2^1, ... 2^(k-1)`, then the sum can be any integer between `0` and `(2^k) - 1`. Since the greatest power of two that can appear in the sequence is `2^17`, the greatest sum that you can build from 18 numbers is `2^18 - 1=262,143`. If a power of two would be missing, there would be a smaller sum that was not possible to achieve.

However, the statement is missing that there may be 2 more numbers in the sequence (at most 20). From these two numbers, you can repeat the same process. Hence, the maximum number to check is actually `(2^18) - 1 + (2^2) - 1`.

You may wonder why we use powers of two and not any other powers. The reason is the binary selection that we perform on the numbers in the input sequence. Either we add a number to the sum or we don't. So, if we represent this selection for number `ni` as a selection variable `si` (either 0 or 1), then the possible sum is:

```
s = s0 * n0 + s1 * n1 + s2 * n2 + ...
```

Now, if we choose the `ni` to be powers of two `ni = 2^i`, then:

```
s = s0 * 2^0 + s1 * 2^1 + s2 * 2^2 + ...
  = sum si * 2^i
```

This is equivalent to the binary representations of numbers (see [Positional Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation)). By definition, different choices for the selection variables will produce different sums. Hence, the number of possible sums is maximal by choosing powers of two in the input sequence.